# S3.putObject is not able to execute

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, function, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
var bucket = 'ashish-3245';
var acl = 'public-read';
var s3prefix = 'DeepSecurityEvents/';
var ext = '.json';

exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    //console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    const message = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
    console.log("records", message);

    var timestamp = event.Records[0].Sns.Timestamp;
    var date = getFormattedDate(new Date(timestamp));
    console.log('from date', date);

    //add 5 random digits to prevent overwriting an existing file if two messages are received at the same ms.
    var random5digits = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90000) + 10000;
    //ie. DeepSecurityEvents/2016/07/20/2016-07-20T15:30:00.000Z12345.json
    var filename = s3prefix + date + '/' + timestamp + random5digits + ext;


    putObjectToS3(message, filename);
    console.log('From S3:', message);
    console.log(filename);

};

function getFormattedDate(d) {
    //returns yyyy/MM/dd
    return d.getFullYear() + '/' + twoDigits(d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + twoDigits(d.getDate());
}

function twoDigits(n) {
    return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n;
}

function putObjectToS3(message, filename) {
    console.log('From async:', message);
    var params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: filename, ACL: acl, Body: message };
    s3.putObject(params, function(err, message) {
        console.log('p SNS:', message);
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(message);
        context.done();
    });
}
```

**Output**

```
kkk

Response
null

Function Logs
START RequestId: 8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e Version: $LATEST
2021-11-21T11:22:16.379Z    8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e    INFO    records omly message
2021-11-21T11:22:16.380Z    8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e    INFO    from date 1970/01/01
2021-11-21T11:22:16.380Z    8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e    INFO    From async: omly message
2021-11-21T11:22:16.492Z    8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e    INFO    From S3: omly message
2021-11-21T11:22:16.505Z    8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e    INFO    DeepSecurityEvents/1970/01/01/1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z99418.json
END RequestId: 8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e
REPORT RequestId: 8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e  Duration: 148.84 ms Billed Duration: 149 ms Memory Size: 400 MB Max Memory Used: 78 MB  Init Duration: 415.78 ms

Request ID
8d6f4394-9b87-49e5-bbec-ad88cf16813e
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [async handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async), so your function finishes before your code actually runs. You can wrap your code in a `Promise` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) to overcome the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you tell me where should i use promise

Answer (score 1):

Your handler is asynchronous, so in order for other asynchronous calls (example: `putObject`) to being able to finish you either:

1. Return a promise which wraps your code (see answer from @Marcin)
2. Use `async-await` pattern. For this what you have to do is the following:

Refactor `putObjectToS3` to return a `promise`:

```
function putObjectToS3(message, filename) {
    console.log('From async:', message);
    const params = { Bucket: bucket, Key: filename, ACL: acl, Body: message };
    try {
        return s3.putObject(params).promise();
    } catch(e) {
        console.err(e);
    }
}
```

In the Lambda handler we must call `putObjectToS3` with `await` as well:

```
const result = await putObjectToS3(message, filename);
console.log('p SNS:', result);
```

Comment: Your `putObjectToS3` function does not return a promise, or anything in fact.

Comment: Neither does the one in the question. Can you please elaborate why would this be a problem?

Comment: That's because the OP doesn't know how to use async/await. Your `putObjectToS3` function would typically `return s3.putObject(params).promise()` which the caller can await (or simply return as the result of the Lambda function handler). As written, your function awaits the promise, then wraps an implicit return value of undefined in a second promise, which the caller then awaits. I should have written "does not *explicitly* return a promise" in my first comment.

Comment: I tried to stay as close as possible to the original implementation. Since there were no return there, I decided to leave it like it is and let the OP adjust it as needed. Nevertheless, I'm updating the answer to return the response from the `putObject` call.
At this point we are guessing what is the intent of the original code from the OP. I think the answer gives a starting point in order for the OP to be able to do more research on the subject of `async/await`.

Comment: The original code returned nothing (and hence the implicit return code was undefined, which was then wrapped in a promise because the function was async). The advantage of explicitly returning a promise is clarity around what the function returns and avoiding unnecessary double await and unwrap/wrap/unwrap of the promise. BTW you would `return s3.putObject(params).promise()` rather than `return await s3.putObject(params).promise()`.

Comment: You are right there, thank you.